# How to Export Microsoft Network Monitor Capture File to .CSV file?

Tags: networking, windows

I've been using Microsoft Network Monitor to capture traffic data, which will eventually be used for data mining purposes and attack detection. It would be much more convenient if I could export the capture to a .csv file. Is there any way to export the capture as a .csv, or, assuming the .cap file is parser friendly, is it possible to analyze the .cap file directly in a language such as Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the capture file into [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (which understands a couple of dozen  popular capture formats, including Microsoft's) and from there export the packet list to a CSV.

Comment: Ah. When I do load the file into Wireshark, it seems to omit the useful columns/fields that were present in Microsoft Network Monitor such as conversation ID, process name, etc. I'm guessing there's no workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight the Frame Summary grid in the Microsoft Network Monitor, right click, and select all, and copy.
The content of the whole capture grid will now be copied to clipboard as a tab separated text. 
Paste to Excel and save as CSV. You can now analyse the CSV in whichever tool you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LogParser in order to convert the cap file into a CSV or even XML.
Check out this link: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/stuartpreston/archive/2006/02/22/2967.aspx